# OCMock. Why does the second of these test pass?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

I am getting up to speed of mock-ing with iOS using OCMock. I wrote a simple mock-ing unit test that passes when - based on the expectation I set - it should fail.

Here is the code:

```
// Scientific Calculator class
@implementation ScientificCalculator

- (NSNumber *)sqrt:(NSNumber *)input {
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqrt([input doubleValue])];
}

@end

// unit test
-(void) testScientificCalculatorSqrt {

    NSNumber *input = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:4];
    ScientificCalculator *scientificCalculator = [[ScientificCalculator alloc] init];

    NSNumber *expected = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:2];

    NSNumber *result = [scientificCalculator sqrt:input];

    STAssertEquals([result doubleValue], [expected doubleValue], nil);

}

// unit test
-(void)testScientificCalculatorMocking {

    // setup
    NSNumber *input = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:44];
    id scientificCalculator = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[ScientificCalculator class]];

    // expect
    NSNumber *expected = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:2];
    [[[scientificCalculator expect] andReturn:expected] sqrt:input];

    // test
    NSNumber *result = [scientificCalculator sqrt:input];

    // verify
    STAssertEquals([result doubleValue], [expected doubleValue], nil);

    [scientificCalculator verify];
}
```

The `testScientificCalculatorMocking` unit test uses `44` as input to `sqrt`. I set the expected values to `2`. Both `STAssertEquals` and `[scientificCalculator verify]` pass successfully.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've told the mock to return 2 (`expected`) when sqrt is called with 44 (`input`). The `result` variable will therefore contain the value 2. You're then comparing `result` (2) and `expected` (2), which will pass.

Comment: I seem to be confused about the difference between a stub and a mock. I thought 'expect' (mock) meant this is the expected value returned. So if the method does not return that value something is wrong and verify should fail. I thought a stub enforced a specific return value regardless of input. Your answer seems to indicate their semantics are very close. I am confused.

Comment: Expect is for verifying interactions with the mock object.

Answer (score 1):

Your first test is the correct way to test something like this. There's no reason to mock your calculator, because its behavior is what you're testing.

Generally you mock things that are orthogonal to what you're testing and may have side effects if you execute them in your test. For example, say you had a method that calculated the square root of Apple's stock price. You might mock the web service call to retrieve the stock price, so your test doesn't make network calls and the price is static in your test. Then you'd pass the pre-defined price to your calculator and verify that the square root value it gives you is correct.

As to `stub` vs. `expect`, `expect` means this method must be called once. `stub` means it may or may not be called, any number of times. In both cases, the `andReturn` part just defines what will be returned when the method is invoked on your mock. Remember, a mock is dumb, so you need to tell it what to return.